# Can I log account and password when to fail to logon on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac, login

I would like to capture the login information as log file to identify the login failure whether someone try to login on my mac or electrical issue.

*** Question: ***

Is there a function on Mac Mavericks 10.9.2 or alternative solution?

*** Requirement: ***

Log the account and password in log file when to fail or success.

*** Reason: ***

To identify whether it's electrical issue, mistype my password or someone log on my Mac.

*** Environment ***

My Mac has virus scan, no shared service and enabled firewall even it's outgoing packet. So, I usually take care of minimum security as much as I can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing attempted passwords used to log in](http://superuser.com/questions/289582/viewing-attempted-passwords-used-to-log-in)

Comment: @Sickest, Thank you for telling me. I got it.